# How to change CenterText Font in PieChart in ios-charts?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I would like to change the  Center Text Font and Font Size of a PieChart. I would like to make it as big as it's possible inside the center circle. Is there any on-board feature that helps me to change the font and font size or do i have to overwrite some Framework classes?

Didn't find any useful information in the documentation :(

That's my basic Chart Formating method:

```
    func setAttributes(view: PieChartView){
    view.legend.enabled = true
    view.descriptionText = ""
    view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    view.drawSliceTextEnabled = false
    view.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: ChartEasingOption.EaseInOutBack)
}
```

Regards!

Comment: Show us the code you have so far and we´ll try to help you.

Comment: I updated my question but in fact the problem is that I don't know which code I could post...I'm looking for the right methods...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The centered text in pie chart is called `centerAttributedText`, in PieChartView. It's `NSAttributedText`, so you can define many custom attributes.

You can simply change its font and size like below:

```
centerText = @"Whatever you like";

[centerText setAttributes:@{
                            NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12.f],
                            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
                            } range:NSMakeRange(0, centerText.length)];

pieChartView.centerAttributedText = centerText;
```

It's in Objective-C, but should be easy for you to translate into swift, since you only need to care about the attributes

Comment: Thank you once again, the NSMakeRange thing is what I am looking for! :)

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**
You can use this code to change font in swift 3.

```
    let myAttribute = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "IranSansMobile", size: 15.0)! ]
    let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: "My String", attributes: myAttribute)

    chart.centerAttributedText = myAttrString
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 5

```
  var pieChartView = PieChartView()
    ...

     let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: "My String", attributes: nil)
     pieChartView.centerAttributedText = myAttrString
```